# how does fgets internally works?

Tags: c, gcc, string

Well it is a basic question but I seem confused enough.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char a[100];
printf("Enter a string\n");
scanf("%s",a);
}
```

Basically the above is what I want to achieve.
If I enter a string

```
James Bond
```

then I want that to be stored in array a.
But the problem is because of presence of a blank space in between only James word is stored.
So how can I solve this one.

**UPDATE**
After the replies given below I understand fgets() would be a better choice. I want to know internal working of fgets as why is it able to store the string with space where as scanf is not able to do the same.

Comment: Use `fgets` instead of `scanf`. Almost always.

Comment: @Chris Lutz I want to know how does fgets works why is fgets able to accept space but not scanf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you need?

- freeBSD: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/stdio/fgets.c?rev=1.14.14.1;content-type=text%2Fplain
- open implementation: https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=7425&lngWId=3
- OWP(dead) http://www.koders.com/c/fid042417FA231704B84308A66E1B82EADEDAB22051.aspx
- ReactOS http://www.koders.com/c/fidEB3507945463053CEFCD518EA0CDFF9EB78E24C9.aspx?s=fgets.c#L1

All implementations scans the input file(or stream) until it reaches \n or EOF, or the `maxSize` param is hit...

Comment: yes man that is exactly what I wanted.Thanks.Let me know what keywords you had used to get that.

Comment: http://www.google.ro/search?q=fgets+source+code&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 1):

scanf reads up until the first whitespace character. The solution is to use fgets, if memory serves me correctly, in your instance it'd be:

`fgets(a, 100, STDIN);`

It will read up to 100 characters (or the first \n) from standard input and store it in a.

Do not use the gets function ever, even if it looks easier.

Comment: @Lainlwakura I want to know how does fgets works why is fgets able to accept space but not scanf and why should one not use gets()?

Comment: I don't know the internals of fgets(), but you should not use gets() because it only takes a pointer to the array. It has absolutely no knowledge of how large the array is and indeed you can overflow it very easily. Some compilers, such as gcc, will actually warn you about using the gets() function

Answer (score 1):

Usually [`scanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) breaks the input at whitespace (space, tab, newline, ...).

For example, the input `" 5 42 -100"` is accepted with `scanf("%d%d%d")` because each `%d` strips the leading whitespace. The same behaviour happens with `%s`.

The only conversion specifiers where the ignoring of leading whitespace doesn't happen are `%%`, `%[` and `%c` (and, for different reasons, `%n`)

```
char input[] = " hello world";
char buf[100];
sscanf(input, "%8c", buf); /* buf contains " hello w" */
sscanf(input, "%8[^o]", buf); /* buf contains " hell" */
```

The [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) function reads as many characters as there are, up to the nest line break.

---

I use [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) for online documentation

Answer (score 0):

You should use gets(a)/fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin) instead of sscanf().

Comment: I want to know internal working of fgets as why is it able to store the string with space where as scanf is not able to do the same.

Comment: @registered-user see  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/ . %s for sscanf work with word. (until a whitespace is found)

Answer (score 0):

Try [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/):

```
char a[100];
printf("Enter a string\n");
fgets(a, sizeof(a), STDIN);
```

To learn more about `STDIN`, [check this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/stdin/).

Comment: I want to know how does fgets works i.e. how is fgets able to store the complete string with white space also.

Comment: @Registered User: please check the link.

Comment: I read your link it talks about stdin whose file descriptor is 0 but I am not able to get how fgets does it.

Comment: @Registered User, you can check your compiler implementation of scanf() and fgets().

Comment: @Registered User, I've never looked into the implementation so I don't know about them. :)